# Is it possible to recreate the ngIf and async pipe behavior in the component file?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I do have two components, a form component, and a thank you page.(full code listings are here: [What is the proper way to share data between two components using rxjs ReplaySubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336187/what-is-the-proper-way-to-share-data-between-two-components-using-rxjs-replaysub))

I'm handling observables using ngIf and the async pipe as follows:

```
<div *ngIf='(message$ | async) as msg'>
...
</div>
```

This is a thank you page template and it works fine.

What I would like to achieve now is: If a user reaches the thank you page, there won't be a value for message$ then I would like to redirect the user to the form content.
I'm trying to reproduce the template behavior (no message$, nothing is displayed) in the component, so I can redirect the user to the form component using router.navigate().

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Note: I'm subscribing to the same observable twice, one subscription will be handled by the async pipe, the other one should be handled by the component. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: kindly mark as  accepted if it answered your question

Comment: @getName thank you a lot for your answer, but I didn't answer my question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use it inside the TS file, as the async pipe, do the subscription and unsubscription automatically without leaks.
For your case, the Angular team just suggests using emitters and inputs to share data between components (and mainly using smart components, the only components can proceed and share data to others, also there is the service sharing data strategy which I'm not a big fun).
Example for sharing data between 2 components using emitters and inputs by passing through parent:
- componentA:

```
<!-- template -->
{{ localVar }}
<button (click)="onSendToParent()">Send localVar to parent</button>
```

And

```
// typescript
localVar = 'could be anything - objects - strings - numbers';
@Ouput() componentAoutput: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

onSendToParent(): void {
    this.componentAoutput.emit(this.localVar);
}
```

- Parent:

```
<!-- template -->
{{ fromComponentA$ | async }}
<component-a (componentAoutput)="fromComponentA$.next($event)"></component-a>
<component-b [componentBinput]="fromComponentA$ | async"></component-b>
```

And

```
// typescript
fromComponentA$: BehaviourSubject<string> = new BehaviourSubject('initial value');
```

- componentB:

```
<!-- template -->
{{ componentBinput }}
```

And

```
// typescript
@Input() componentBinput: string;

// if need you can affect its value to a new created subject
componentBinput$: BehaviourSubject<string> = new BehaviourSubject(this.componentBinput);
```

You can do sharing data in the other way using the same strategy, this strategy is a best practice recommended by angular experts, I answered by this example because I believe the problems you're getting implementing your feature come from data sharing and not manipulating observables and to remind, it's very bad practice to nest 2 subscribes, or to use subscribes on TS file when you can avoid that by using the async pipe on template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how exactly are you able to work with once Observable with two subscriptions.

If you want to navigate the user away using `router.navigate(...)` and you already have subscribed to the `Observable` in your TypeScript Class, why not use the same variable in your Template and remove the `async` pipe from your template.

This is how it would look like in code:

In your Component Class:

```
msg;

...

message$.subscribe(message => {
  if (!message) {
    this.router.navigate(...);
  } else {
    this.msg = message;
  }
});
```

And in your Template:

```
<div *ngIf='msg'>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm able to work with two subscribers because I'm using a subject. If I refresh the thank you page, I want to redirect the user to the form page. (no value = no form was submitted). That's why I asked how ngIf together with the async pipe works, I need to replicate that behavior. In my case, the observable will never emit a value if you refresh the thank you page. I just don't want the user to see the thank you page before filling the form.

Comment: Can you emit an empty string for refresh? If you do that, the `if` condition will still get satisfied and since you're binding to `msg` in `*ngIf` the thank you message won't show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but no, it doesn't work. In order to process the extra element I should add extra logic, and that doesn't seem to be the result that I'm looking for. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I was using a ReplaySubject instead of a BehaviorSubject. That was not right, In the end, I omitted the most important part. A BehaviorSubject is useful to check how a value evolves over time.

I switched to a BehaviorSubject because it will always emit the last value upon subscription, then, there is no need to add any extra logic or to emit any extra values, or to check if the observable is "empty".

Comment: actually it's not completely true, as the behaviourSubject has an initial value that you specify when creating it, and it always stores the last emitted one, for a replaySubject, it has the ability to have multiple values to store, you specify that when you create it, but it doesn't have an initial value ^^ that's the real difference actually